# What is the difference between blocking and non-blocking mode in IPython.parallel in load_balanced_mode()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipython, ipython-parallel

In all the examples I found for ipython:

it seems that when using a load-balanced view block is set to False.

I was wondering why?

Also, is it possible to set it to True and what implication would that have?

I know this may be a basic question but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer as a newbie.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the thing is blocking and non-blocking is nothing but the two different ways to get your output ->

1. Either you want to have output of all the commands at last so that processor will be used in executing the algorithmic command rather than producing an output, for this processor need to block the other commands and this mode is known as Blocking mode in which we have to set directViewName.block=TRUE
2. Or you want to have the output as soon as it is generated for this you need to specify the processor that it should not block the commands i.e directViewName.block=FALSE
   and this mode is Non-Blocking mode.

And now if you'll set directViewName.block=TRUE in Non Blocking mode then it is no more NBM.

**Programming point of view --**

Blocking execution

In blocking mode, the DirectView object (called dview in these examples) submits the command to the controller, which places the command in the engines’ queues for execution. The apply() call then blocks until the engines are done executing the command.

```
   {
    In [2]: dview = rc[:] # A DirectView of all engines
    In [3]: dview.block=True
    In [4]: dview['a'] = 5
    In [5]: dview['b'] = 10
    In [6]: dview.apply(lambda x: a+b+x, 27)
    Out[6]: [42, 42, 42, 42]
   }
```

Non-blocking execution

In non-blocking mode, apply() submits the command to be executed and then returns a AsyncResult object immediately. The AsyncResult object gives you a way of getting a result at a later time through its get() method.
This allows you to quickly submit long running commands without blocking your local Python/IPython session.

```
    {
    In [6]: def wait(t):
    import time
    tic = time.time()
    time.sleep(t)
    return time.time()-tic

   # In non-blocking mode
   In [7]: ar = dview.apply_async(wait, 2)

   # Now block for the result
   In [8]: ar.get()
   Out[8]: [2.0006198883056641, 1.9997570514678955, 1.9996809959411621,2.0003249645233154]

  # Again in non-blocking mode
  In [9]: ar = dview.apply_async(wait, 10)

  # Poll to see if the result is ready
  In [10]: ar.ready()
  Out[10]: False

  # ask for the result, but wait a maximum of 1 second:
  In [45]: ar.get(1)
  }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. So the thing that I'm curious about is the load-balanced view (usually written as lview in the examples not the DirectView. I just don't get why block is always set to false before that? could you please elaborate a bit on that in your answer?